# jQuery give user friendly error message on fail

Tags: jquery

I handle server exceptions with `$.ajax`:

```
.fail(function (qXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
     $('#loadingDiv').hide();
     console.log(qXHR.responseText);
     console.log(textStatus);
     console.log(errorThrown);
     $('#errorMessage').text(qXHR + "::" + textStatus + "::" + errorThrown);
});
```

Sample Error: `[object Object]::error::Internal Server Error`

When I throw an `ApplicationException` from the server I want to tell the user to `try searching for something more specific`.

"Internal Server Error" is too vague.  The `object.responseText` has the specific error information, but it's hidden in piles of HTML.

How can I give the user better information based on the exception that occurred without overloading them with `qxHR.responseText`?

Comment: You could setup an array of actual errors mapped to something that is friendlier and replace as needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't generate an HTTP error when the server code detects invalid input. Generate a successful response, but put an error message into the response structure (use JSON, for instance). Then have the `.done()` handler check whether `response.error` is filled in, and display that.